# Only the home route working on my EC2 instance server for AWS for Laravel 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-4

I am trying to set up my laravel project on my EC2 Instance for AWS.  I have successfully uploaded the files to the server using SFTP, and I rewrote the 000-default.conf file to point to the public folder of the project.

The home route is loading fine, but none of the other routes are working?  Any idea what is going on here?  They all work fine on local host (MAMP) and on other servers.

All of the other routes show a NOT FOUND page (The requested URL /fans was not found on this server (for instance) )

Comment: Does `index.php/fans` work?

Comment: it does, but then none of the image paths work because I have it using pretty urls (so index.php doesn't show up).  So ec2-etc..etc../fans doesn't work, but ec2-etc..etc../index.php/fans does.

Comment: Sounds like a `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled then. Not sure how EC2 instances work, but if you can SSH in an it's Apache then just enable it with `a2enmod rewrite` then restart Apache.

Comment: which apache file do I put this in?

Comment: It's a command, so simply run `a2enmod rewrite`, you may need to elevate yourself with `sudo`, not sure how it works on Amazon.

Comment: I performed this command, and restarted apache, but I am still getting the not found error on my routes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

First in 000-default.conf

Make Document Root point to your public folder:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your/laravel-project-folder/public/
```

Then add this to end of the 000-default.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/your/laravel-project-folder/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Last two steps:

run this as root user:

```
1. sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. service apache2 restart
```

Now everything was working fine for me.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: AllowOverride All 
It's just allow to your web files acceess from your server. Normally its does not able to access the file that's why we set AllowOverride All. There is no risk for your web to miscellaneous access. It's say allow access for .htaccess file from apache2 server. Here is the link for more details about AllowOverride All.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 8):

For people who have this issue in the future:

All I had to do was add:

```
<Directory /var/www>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to my `000-default.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory.

Place it right under the DocumentRoot line.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I use Laravel5.2 on AWS.
Can you see the welcome page after you deploy laravel on AWS? You can use the following to access the welcome page.
/public/index.php

If you can do above, then you modify your route.php in the app/Http/ folder, like this:

```
Route::get('/convert/{name}', function ($name) {
     return str_plural($name);
});
```

After that you can try "/public/index.php/convert/123".
Then you will see "123s" on the screen.

It is really tricky to visit your route with /public/index.php/, it waste long time for me to fix this problem.